# Switch back to multi column after one column

Tags: two-column

I am using this multicol tex template for a paper. For a certain portion I have to switch to one column format. Then after that paragraph or text, I have to switch back to multi column format. How can I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you are using e.g. `twocolumn` as an option passed to a standard class such as `article`, you could just do `\onecolumn` then `\twocolumn`. This will start a new page each time, though. `multicols` avoids that (but introduces some other complications of its own). Very hard to say anything helpful with an MWE.

Comment: @cfr General answer or *unclear*?

Comment: @Johannes_B Unclear, I think. 'multicol... template' could mean anything at all.

Comment: @cfr Alright, voted.